# The incoming tabular data stream (TDS) remote procedure call (RPC) protocol stream is incorrect. The RPC name is invalid?

Tags: javascript, sql-server, node.js, stored-procedures

I am working on a stored procedure if date is exists then fetch records else last 90 days data procedure is working fine but if i send input through code , i am getting a The incoming tabular data stream (TDS) remote procedure call (RPC) protocol stream is incorrect .

Here is my procedure:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[get_audit_list_for_sites_list_enh]
    (@site_list VARCHAR(MAX),
     @ip_audit_dttm_from DATETIME = NULL,
     @ip_audit_dttm_to DATETIME = NULL)
/**************************************************************************************************
* Name           : get_accepted_terms_da_user
*
* Description    : This Procedure is to get the user activity, user, admin etc details for auditing
*
* Author         : Sandeep (rajsa06)
*
* Date Written   : 11th Jan 2017
*
***************************************************************************************************
* Called By
* None.
*
* Objects                          S         I        U       D       E
* dbo.user_info                    X
* dbo.user_audit                   X
*
* Called Objects
* None.
**************************************************************************************************/
AS 
BEGIN
    IF (@ip_audit_dttm_from IS NULL AND  @ip_audit_dttm_to IS NULL)
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @t_sites TABLE (site_id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY)

        INSERT INTO @t_sites (site_id)
            SELECT integer_id
            FROM dbo.dba_tfn_split_commaseparated_int_string(@site_list)

        SELECT 
            a.site_id AS siteId,
            a.activity AS activity,
            a.activity_desc AS activityDesc,
            a.audit_dttm AS auditDate,
            b.first_name AS userFirstName,
            b.last_name AS userLastName,
            b.login_name AS userEmail,
            CONCAT(c.first_name,' ', c.last_name) AS adminName
        FROM   
            (SELECT * 
             FROM dbo.user_audit 
             WHERE site_id IN (SELECT site_id FROM @t_sites) 
               AND audit_dttm >= DATEADD(day, -90, GETDATE())) a
        INNER JOIN 
            dbo.user_info b ON a.user_id = b.user_id
        INNER JOIN 
            dbo.user_info c ON a.da_user_id = c.user_id 
        ORDER BY 
            auditDate DESC
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @t_sites (site_id)
            SELECT integer_id
            FROM dbo.dba_tfn_split_commaseparated_int_string(@site_list)

        SELECT  
            a.site_id AS siteId, a.activity AS activity,
            a.activity_desc AS activityDesc, a.audit_dttm AS auditDate,
            b.first_name AS userFirstName, b.last_name AS userLastName,
            b.login_name AS userEmail,
            CONCAT(c.first_name,' ', c.last_name) AS adminName
        FROM   
            (SELECT * FROM dbo.user_audit 
             WHERE site_id IN (SELECT site_id FROM @t_sites) 
               AND audit_dttm >= @ip_audit_dttm_from 
               AND audit_dttm <= @ip_audit_dttm_to) a
        INNER JOIN 
            dbo.user_info b ON a.user_id = b.user_id
        INNER JOIN 
            dbo.user_info c ON a.da_user_id = c.user_id 
        ORDER BY 
            auditDate DESC
    END
END
```

Here is my Node.js code .

```
new MsSqlWrapper()
          .runStoredProcedure({
             storedProcedureName:
                constants.storedProcedures.get_audit_list_for_sites_list_enh,

            inputs: [

              {
                name: 'site_list',
                value: siteIdList.data.details
              },
              {
                name: 'ip_audit_dttm_from',
                value: fromDate
              },
              {
                name: 'ip_audit_dttm_to',
                value: toDate
              }
            ]
          })
```

And my inputs :

```
"input": {
            "userId": "336931",
            "connectSiteId": "999999",
            "fromDate": "2009-10-21 08:20:39.477",
            "toDate": "2009-12-21 08:20:39.477"
          }
```

Comment: The `runStoreProc` code?

Comment: If you search around the web (like I am right now) you'll see that there's a number of different causes for this issue. Without the *full* error text (there's a couple of different things that can follow "protocol stream is incorrect"), it would be impossible to judge what the problem here is. Just FYI if you ever expect actual help.

Answer (score 1):

I have same error message as this because I had changed my call to use SQL 'Text' instead of a 'stored procedure', so the wrong CommandType is another thing that can cause this fault.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
```